# Error in android build gradle file while running the application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I started doing chatbot with firebase and created an account and added it to my android application , but it is showing an error in build gradle file related to dimen.xml.

The Dimen.xml file is not changed or given by me and it is default one.

**Below is the error I am getting:**

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: we need a whole lot more info to be able to help, what does the error say ? what does the code look like ?

Comment: What part of code would you like to see? Could you also give me a gist of the info that you need?

Comment: have a look at [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you understand, usually we need enough information to actually recreate the problem, consider your current post from our perspective, we can't really recreate anything that you've posted